# How to split string (object) to 'save' in new item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I get this json file:

```
var data = [  
   {  
      "id":"1",      
      "yMonth":"201901",
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",      
      "yMonth":"201902",
   },
   {  
      "id":"3",      
      "yMonth":"201802",
   },
   {  
      "id":"4",      
      "yMonth":"202003",
   }
]
```

My `yMonth` contains concatenated year and month (201901 -> year: 2019, month: 01). So, I'm trying to split my `yMonth` for two new items sorting out by `year` and `month`.

To get this kind of return:

```
[  
    {  
      "id":"1",      
      "year":"2019",
      "month":"01",
    },
    {  
      "id":"2",      
      "year":"2019",
      "month":"02",
    },
    {  
      "id":"3",      
      "year":"2018",
      "month":"02",
    },
    {  
      "id":"4",      
      "year":"2020",
      "month":"03",
    }
]
```

One way I thought of doing is starting like this:

```
data.forEach(item => {
  item.yMonth..... 
   //Split string, maybe save temporarily in aux variable, create a new array with: `year` and `month` items
 })
```

Someone can help me? I'm really lost in how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
 item.month = item.yMonth.slice(4);
 item.year = item.yMonth.slice(0, 4);
 delete item.yMonth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array with `Array.map()`. In the map separate `yMonth` from the object via destructuring and rest synatx. Get the year and month using `String.match()` with a RegExp, add them to the rest of the object with object spread:

```js
const data = [{"id":"1","yMonth":"201901"},{"id":"2","yMonth":"201902"},{"id":"3","yMonth":"201802"},{"id":"4","yMonth":"202003"}]

const result = data.map(({ yMonth, ...rest }) => {
  const [, year, month] = yMonth.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})/)
  
  return {
    ...rest,
    year,
    month,
  };
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `map` and inside of the handler use the function `match` to capture the year and month.

```js
var data = [     {        "id":"1",            "yMonth":"201901",   },   {        "id":"2",            "yMonth":"201902",   },   {        "id":"3",            "yMonth":"201802",   },   {        "id":"4",            "yMonth":"202003",   }],
    result = data.map(({yMonth, ...attr}) => {
      var [year, month] = yMonth.match(/[0-9]{2,4}/g);  
      return {...attr, year, month};
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
let index  = 2 //from where you want to split
data.map(d=>{
   d.month=d.yMonth.substring(0, index);
   d.year = d.yMonth.substring(index);
   delete yMonth;
  return d;
})
```